# Why can't I populate a login form with a FactoryGirl.create(:user)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I'm trying to test a login form with FactoryGirl, Rspec, and Capybara.

I can test the signup form by running `FactoryGirl.build(:user)`, but I can't login a user that is created by Factory Girl with `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`. Here's my failing test:

```
it "logs in a factory girl user" do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      visit login_path
      fill_in "Email",    :with => user.email
      fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
      check "Remember me"
      click_button "Log in"
      page.should have_content("Logged in!")
end
```

It seems that you should use `FactoryGirl.build(:user)` to test the signup form, but then you should use `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` with to save a new user to the database and then test the login process with that user. But for some reason it can't pull that user from the database and insert it into the form. If I add `save_and_open_page` after the `fill_in "Email" line`, then email field is still blank.

Is this not the proper way to test with Rspec and Factory Girl? I'd like to do it this way so that I can log in as regular users and admin users and test different features in the browser with capybara. Do I need to create a utility method such as `signup_and_login_user` where I use `FactoryGirl.build(:user)` then navigate through the signup and login forms with capybara. Then I just use this method each time I need to login a user in a test?

Comment: loooks good, should work? maybe there is a problem with hashing the password?

Comment: do you have another email field in your html? maybe it fills the wrong one

Comment: and are you sure that your factory user.email is not blank or nil?

Comment: I'm using Sorcery for authentication, so maybe there is something to that that I should look into. It's not filling out any field, but there isn't an extra email field in the html. It's not nil either because this passes https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/5629126

Comment: Could it be related to this issue: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/125#issuecomment-18288901

Comment: Have you the solution?